# What is the difference between x.view(x.size(0), -1) and torch.nn.Flatten() layer and torch.flatten(x)? pytorch question

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm quite curious on what's the difference between using view(,-1) and flatten like the simple code here:

Since I found that the size and data all flatten to one dimension.

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor, Lambda, Compose
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = torch.rand(3,256,256)
x.size()

a = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
print('after view:',a.size())

m = nn.Sequential(nn.Flatten())
y = m(x)
print('after nn flatten:',y.size())
z = torch.flatten(x)
print('after torch flatten:',y.size())
```

And also, it seems there is no difference between = and =.contiguous which said :Returns a contiguous in memory tensor containing the same data as self tensor. but for me, it seems just return the self tensor but not copy or new tensor with same data.

```py
c = y
print(c)
b = y.contiguous()
print(b)

# change original data
y[0][0]=1
print(b)
print(c)
print(y)
```

Comment: and I see that the `contiguous` is not mean copying the memory but letting tensor data in contiguous memory. It's usually used before doing the view step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A view is a way to modify the way you look at your data without modifying the data itself:

- [`torch.view`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.view.html?highlight=view#torch.Tensor.view) returns a view on the data: the data is not copied, only the "window" which you look through on the data changes
- `torch.flatten` returns a one-dimensional output from a multi-dimensional input. It may not copy the data if

> [the] input can be viewed as the flattened shape ([source](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html?highlight=flatten#torch.flatten))

- `torch.nn.Flatten` is just a [wrapper](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/flatten.html#Flatten) for convenience around `torch.flatten`

Contiugous data just means that the data is linearly adressable in memory, e.g. for two dimension data this would mean that element `[i][j]` is at position `i * num_columns + j`. If this is already the case then [`.contiguous`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.contiguous.html?highlight=contiguous#torch.Tensor.contiguous) will not change your data or copy anything.

Comment: That's really clear, thank you very much.